# Code-oss process is sleeping when launched from terminal

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code

When I am starting vs-code (code-oss) from terminal, The process instantly goes to sleep.

```
abhinav@abhinav-sol ~/Project $ code-oss .
```

[image: Process tab in terminal]

This is not happening when I launch code directly from desktop icon. But I can't do that because my java environment is created by sdkman and is only detectable by vscode if I launch it from command line. Also it is just faster to open project folder directly from command line.

<del>This has been only happening since past few days. I tried roll backing the update thinking this was caused by update, but it doesn't work either.</del>
*edit: I did a full system rollback and turns out, older version of code-oss works.*

Any idea why this is happening and how to resolve it?

**EDIT:**
After a bit of testing, it feels like microsoft has made another deliberate attempt to make 3rd-party binaries less usable. I tried rollbacking the update on my manjaro machine and it was working, I updated it, and it stopped working from terminal. I downloaded the official microsoft vscode binary for vscode, and it was working properly. Only code-oss was not working. I installed vscodium, it also created sleeping process when launched from terminal. I am aware that remote-ssh extension doesn't work on 3rd-party build, this looks like another attempt to slow down the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, Yes! this is an attempt to control the community.

Enough Conspiracy theory about the big tech, Here is the real Solution.

For temporary workaround, pass `--disable-crash-reporter` flag when launching from terminal. If you want to make it more permanent, modify `~/.vscode/argv.json` to disable crash-reporter.

```json
{
  ...
    // Allows to disable crash reporting.
    // Should restart the app if the value is changed.
    "enable-crash-reporter": true, 
  ...
}
```

What exactly changed in crash-reporter mechanism that caused it is bit technical for me to grasp but there is the [github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/127585) Which was closed by microsoft as "product decision". In simple terms, Now any 3rd party build like vscodium or distro's package team need to manually apply the patch for every release. This won't be fixed in upstream as they have already rejected the pull request which fixes this for the community.

**On a positive note, Once I disabled the crash-reporter, App Startup time has been significantly improved .**